# overflow auto not working in firefox it is working good in chrome

Tags: html, css

i have one chat application,when chat message get overflow then scrollbar goes up ratherthan down in firefox,it is working good in chrome pls help anybody

```
#header {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#logo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}
#logo img {
    display: block;
}
#tagline {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tagline img {
    display: block;
}
.logwrapper {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius-topleft: 0.5em;
    border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 6.5em;
    /* Dimensions for IE: */
    /*_width: 96%;
    _height: 250px;*/
}
.logbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0.5em;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    /* Dimensions for IE: */
   /* _width: 97%;
    _height: 230px;*/
}
.logitem {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.controlwrapper {
    padding-right: 176px;
}
.inconversation .controlwrapper {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.logwrapper {
    margin-right: 176px;
    _width: 75%;
}
.inconversation .logwrapper {
    _width: 96%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a fix or dynamic height to the .logbox